# Even or odd in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

This is table structure

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I need result like this

```
id  even  odd
1   0     1
2   1     0
3   0     1
4   1     0
5   0     1
6   1     0
```

I tried

```
select id %2=0 then 1 else 0 end or id%2 <>0 then 1 else 0 odd 
from table
```

Comment: Have a look at the [CASE statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

```
select 
  id, 
  ~id & 1, 
  id & 1 
from t
```

Comment: If a number's low bit is set its odd, else its even. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5700927/246342) The `~` is simply a bitwise negation to invert the 1/0 to get the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [`CASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) keyword.  It works very similarly to what you're trying to do in your `SELECT` statement.  In addition, if you want to select multiple columns, separate them with a comma.  The [`OR`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188361.aspx) keyword is used for combining logical conditions in your query, not for specifying multiple columns.

An example of how you could use `CASE` in your query would be as follows:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN id %2=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Even,
       [column2]
FROM   [TableName]
```

Answer (score 1):

The table structure is just Id?

you could try this!

```
 select *,
    case when id %2=0 then 1 else 0 end as even,
    case when id %2 <>0 then 1 else 0 end as odd
    from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but your syntax is a bit off. I'd use a `CASE` statement to create the `even` column, and then a calculate `odd` accordingly:

```
SELECT id, even, ABS(even - 1) AS odd
FROM   (SELECT id, CASE WHEN id % 2 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS even
        FROM   my_table)
```