# cannot understand what is meant by (b&1) in this code snippet of C

Tags: c

```
inline ll modinv(ll a , ll b)
{
    ll res=1;
    while (b)
    {
        if(b&1)
            res = (res*a)%mod;
        a=(a*a)%mod;
        b=b/2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

does it mean if condition would be fulfilled only if b==1.

Comment: it would mean the condition would be fulfilled only if b was an odd number.

Comment: Where is `ll` defined

Comment: @zzxyz With a little more explanation that is an answer. Why don't you make one?

Comment: Did you just edit your question to replace a perfectly useable code quote with an annoying picture of code? Generally, for textual information text is more appreciated here than pictures of code.

Comment: Please do not use a picture of any code in questions or answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an integer is even or odd using bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700911/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd-using-bitwise-operators)

Comment: @phoxis It's probably just a simple `#define ll long long` or something of the nature. Not really relevant to the question however.

Comment: @phoxis: Given the name, I'd guess it's probably `long long`, though `unsigned long long` might make more sense.  Behavior of the code will likely not be meaningful if `a*a` is greater than the maximum value of type `ll`, or if either operand is negative.

Comment: I can guess that, but just curious.

Comment: Indenting the conditional part after `if` is a good idea, but keep the indentation otherwise consistent and do not indent too much. You might have mixed tabulators and blanks, that can easily get in the way with correct indentation. Stick to blanks is what I recommend. I hope I helped to get what you intended. If I broke something please take my apology.

Comment: Also, be more careful in order not to loose good edits by other people. If you review your changes, you will see that you undid some nice (if not world-shaking) edits by a helpful other editor. Consider adding them again.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your efforts .You helped me solve my question . @Yunnosch Since i've just joined stackoverflow i am trying to figure out how to post the question properly , i am really sorry for the inconvenience and i will surely try to add the recommended edits .Thank you once again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` is a bitwise operator in this case. When you do `b&1` you have an integer `b` say 13 in decimal and the number `1`.

```
         d7 d6 d5 d4 d3 d2 d1 d0
b = 13 =  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1 
     1 =  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
          -----------------------  after bitwise and operator
          0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Above each bit of `b` is logically `&`ed with corresponding bit of binary representation of `1`. Because one of the integers is `1` which has only one `1` at position `d0`, all the bitwise and operator will evaluate to `0` in all the positions from `d7` to `d1`, and because the outcome of `d0` in the result will depend on what is present in `d0` of your variable `b`.

All the odd numbers have a `1` in their binary representation at `d0` position. All the even numbers have a `0` in their binary representation at `d0` position.

Therefore this is a way to check what digit is present at `d0`. If it is `1` the outcome of `b&1` will be `1`, else it will be `0`, which will enable us to determine if the integer is even or odd, in this case.

Although similar application of  bitwise operator gives you to check which bit of an integer is `1` or `0`, set a specific bit in an integer etc.

**EDIT**

@chux Makes some pretty good points, see the answer. Be aware of the one's complement issue (but possibly you will never encounter it unless you are using some weird hardware). Also, these days, checking for odd-even the modulus operator will be better as good compilers can make efficient code.

Answer (score 5):

[It is a bitwise operation, checking if `b` is odd or even.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700911/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd-using-bitwise-operators)

```
if (number & 1) {
  // Number is Odd.
} else {
  // Number is Even.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> what is meant by `(b&1)` in this code snippet of C (?)

It is attempting to test odd-ness on type `ll` - perhaps `long long`.  This is done by masking (*anding*) the least significant bit.

---

Given that an `int` could use [One's complement)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), (and that likely only applies to machines in the computer graveyard),  `b&1` does not work for odd/even test with negative values on those rare machines.

`if(b%2)` does work on those and all others platforms to test odd-ness.

A common concern is that `b%2` will perform a division, rather than a fast *and*.  This may be true of weak compilers, yet a modern compile can be expected to emit efficient code ( using an *and* instruction) with `if(b%2)`.

Code for clarity.

---

BTW: `inline ll modinv(ll a , ll b)` is UB or returns the wrong value when `res*a` or `a*a` overflows [@ supercat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50517336/cannot-understand-what-is-meant-by-b1-in-this-code-snippet-of-c/50518792#comment88047642_50517336) and with the pathological case of `mod == 1`.