# Find the Min Even Integer and Max Even Integer in an Array

Tags: c, arrays, max, min

```
int  i,max,min;
int  A[11];
    min = A[1];
    max = A[1];
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        if(min > A[i] && A[i]%2 ==0 )  min = A[i];
        if(max < A[i] && A[i]%2 ==0 ) max = A[i];
    }
    printf("Minimum  Even : %d\n",min);
    printf("Maximum  Even : %d\n",max);
    getch();
}
```

When I fill my array with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Why is the minimum even number equal to 1?

[image]

Comment: Why do you waste an extra index of the array?

Comment: Don't put images to show output. Use `proper formatting `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This test case exposes one of the dark sides of your code where you have initialized your `min` and `max` to `A[1]` regardless of whether `A[1]` is odd or even.

**Problem:**

There may be cases where the array does not contain any even number. In such cases, you may wish to print so instead of printing `-1` or `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX`.

If you are new to `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`, [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/int_max-int_min-cc-applications/) will serve as a starter before proceeding to the solution.

**Solution:**

*This solution modifies your code in such a way that it handles all the cases given that you provide the inputs without any error.*

1. Have a [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402125/what-is-a-flag-variable) to know whether you found your `min` and `max`:

   ```
   int foundAnswer = 0;
   ```
2. Add the header file `limits.h` and initialize your `min` and `max` as
   follows:

   ```
   min = INT_MAX;
   max = INT_MIN;
   ```
3. Modify your loop such that the flag serves a purpose:

   ***Note:***

   Don't waste the zeroth index of your array without any reason.
   Modify your array declaration and input loop accordingly before
   changing this one.

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i)
   {
    if (A[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
     foundAnswer = 1;
     if (A[i] < min) min = A[i];
     if (A[i] > max) max = A[i];
    }
   }
   ```
4. Modify your printing code slightly so that all the cases are
   covered.

   ```
   if (foundAnswer)
   {
    // Print min
    // Print max
   }
   else
   {
    // Print "min and max not found"
   }
   ```

**Bonus:**

You can learn from the following links in order to optimize your code:

1. [How do I check if an integer is even or odd using bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700911/how-do-i-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd-using-bitwise-operators)
2. The algorithms discussed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-and-minimum-in-an-array/) will provide you with a better time complexity to achieve the same.

Comment: Your bug report and the first tip is based on the case where all the elements of the array are similar. I have updated my solution with respect to your suggestions. Thank you @ikegami

Comment: I appreciate the fact that `INT_MAX` is odd. I have replaced `<=` and `>=` with `<` and `>`. However, the real reason to do so is that `min` and `max` are initialized to `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` respectively. Re *"I said that findmin and findmax were always the same":* You also followed it up with adding an `else` before my second `if` into the code which is also visible in the edit history. That would fail in the case where the array size is 1 and the only element is even. Anyways, I have updated my code as needed @ikegami

Comment: Re: *"Ah yes, that's a bug."* No worries, it was a nice time working on this answer with you. I'm still a student; you gave me some teamwork experience. Your suggestions and bug reports were spot on. Thank you @ikegami

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you initialize `min` and `max` to an value that might not be even.

The following is an efficient solution that handles empty arrays, arrays containing only odd numbers, and arrays containing only `INT_MAX`:

```
int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
size_t n = 10;

size_t found_even = 0;
int min, max;
while (n--) {
   int val = A[n];
   if ((A[n] & 1) == 0) {  // Assumes a 2's complement machine.
      if (found_even++) {
         if      (A[n] < min) min = A[n];
         else if (A[n] > max) max = A[n];
      } else {
         min = val;
         max = val;
      }
   }
}

if (found_even) {
   printf("Minimum even: %d\n", min);
   printf("Maximum even: %d\n", max);
} else {
   printf("Minimum even: <none>\n");
   printf("Maximum even: <none>\n");
}
```

Slightly faster:

```
int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
size_t n = 10;

int found_even = 0;
int min, max;
while (n--) {
   int val = A[n];
   if ((A[n] & 1) == 0) {  // Assumes a 2's complement machine.
      min = val;
      max = val;
      found_even = 1;
      break;
   }
}

if (found_even) {
   while (n--) {
      if ((A[n] & 1) == 0) {
         if      (A[n] < min) min = A[n];
         else if (A[n] > max) max = A[n];
      }
   }

   printf("Minimum even: %d\n", min);
   printf("Maximum even: %d\n", max);
} else {
   printf("Minimum even: <none>\n");
   printf("Maximum even: <none>\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`min = A[1];`
Here min is already initialized to 1. So,

`if(min > A[i] && A[i]%2 ==0 )  min = A[i];`
condition will never be true.

Add the header file `limits.h` and initialize
`min=INT_MAX; 
max=INT_MIN;`

Comment: Using `min = INT_MAX` doesn't work if the array is populated entirely with values equal to `INT_MAX` (an odd number on 2's complement machines)

Comment: @ikegami corner cases like that may be handled in code..this is just snippet.

Comment: What is the smallest even number if all numbers are odd?